The First Singular Homology Group $H_1(X)$ and the Fundamental Group
THEOREM. Let $X$ be a topological space and let $x_0\in X$ a point. The map $\varphi\colon\pi_1(X,x_0)\to H_1(X)$ defined by $[\sigma]_{\simeq}\mapsto[\sigma]_{\sim}$ is well defined and it is a homomorphism of groups.
Proof.
First of all, we verify that the map is well defined. Let $\sigma_0,\sigma_1\colon\Delta^1\to X$ two loops in $X$ based in $x_0$ (hence, $\sigma_0(1,0)=\sigma_0(0,1)=\sigma_1(1,0)=\sigma_1(0,1)=x_0$) and let us assume that there exists an homotopy $F\colon\Delta^1\times I\to X$ from $\sigma_0$ to $\sigma_1$, i.e. $F((t_0,t_1),j)=\sigma_j(t_0,t_1)$ for all $j\in\{0,1\}$, $F((1,0),s)=x_0=F((0,1),s)$ for all $s\in I=[0,1]$. The map $F$ factors like $F=\eta\circ\theta$ where $\theta\colon\Delta^1\times I\to\Delta^2, \theta(t_0,t_1,s)=(t_0,t_1(1-s),t_1s)$. "It is easy to verify that the map $\eta$ is continous and that $\partial_2\eta=\sigma_0-\sigma_1+constant$."
My problem. I don't understand how explicitly the $2$-singular simplex $\eta$ is defined. I thought that a possible idea was to define $\eta(x,y,z)=F\bigg((x,y+z),\frac{z}{y+z}\bigg)$ but I don't think that this idea works. Can anyone help me, please?
I'm using Tammo Tom Diek's book, but I'm also reading Spanier, Munkres and Bredon. None of these books writes clearly who is $\eta$. For istance, Munkres says that $\eta$ is the map that is constant along the straight lines of $\Delta^2$ that are perpendicular to the edge $[e_0,e_2]$ and that is $\sigma_1$ on the edge $[e_0,e_1]$ and $\sigma_0$ on the edge $[e_1,e_2]$. But I would like to have a clear expression for $\eta(x,y,z)$ and I would like to verify precisely that $\eta$ is continous.

Your idea works just fine; you just have to decide (arbitrarily) what happens when $y + z = 0$.

@NaïmFavier I think that I cannot choose arbitrarily because  the map $\eta$ has to be continuous. It comes me in mind to define $\eta(1,0,0):=x_0$ but I'm not sure that $\eta$ is continuous.

It is continuous, because $\theta$ is a quotient map and $F$ descends to the quotient.

@NaïmFavier What do you formally mean by "$\theta$ Is a quotient map"? Is It the canonical projection with respect some equivalence relation?

It is a quotient map with respect to the equivalence relation on $\Delta_1 \times I$ generated by $((0, 1), a) \sim ((0, 1), b)$. The universal property of quotients gives you $\eta$ (or just its continuity).

I don't find this proof the most conceptually enlightening but it is efficient. I will discuss that and also, for me, a nicer proof. As commented, $\theta$ is a quotient map. If you think carefully enough, you realise $\theta$ is a continuous surjection of compact Hausdorff spaces and that $\theta(p)=\theta(q)$ only for $p,q$ both lying on the line $(1,0,\lambda)_{\lambda\in I}$. Hence it is the quotient $\Delta^1\times I/e_0\times I$. $F$ is constant on $e_0\times I$ so necessarily factors as $\eta\theta$ for a uniquely determined, automatically continuous, map $\theta$. We don't need any formulas; we can even determine $\partial\eta$ without knowing formulas for it, because the $2$nd, $1$st and $0$th edges of the $2$-simplex are identifiable with the maps $\Delta^1\to\Delta^2$ given by $\theta(x,y,0)$, $\theta(x,y,1)$, $\theta(0,1,y)$ respectively and $\eta$'s compositions with these are $F(x,y,0)=\sigma_1(x,y),F(x,y,1)=\sigma_2(x,y)$ and $F(0,1,y)=x_0$ respectively. So, $\sigma_1-\sigma_2=\partial\eta-\partial\text{const}(x_0)$ is a boundary.

If you want to explicitly get $\eta$, then your formula is exactly correct for $(x,y,z)\neq(1,0,0)$. It must be, since $F=\eta\theta$ determines it thusly. Now, when is $\theta$ equal to $(1,0,0)$? On the collapsed line $e_0\times I$. So $\eta(1,0,0)=\eta(\theta(1,0,s))=F(1,0,s)=x_0$ for any choice of $s\in I$ is how it must be defined. By the quotient topology considerations, I know $\eta$ is continuous.
But to see this explicitly, the only issue is checking continuity at this vertex $(1,0,0)$ (marked green in my image) and for that, if $U$ is any neighbourhood of $x_0$ observe $F^{-1}(U)$ is a neighbourhood of $e_0\times I$, which is compact; by the tube lemma principle, we know there is $\delta>0$ such that $(1-t,t,s)\in F^{-1}(U)$ for $0\le t<\delta$. Now consider the open neighbourhood $B((1,0,0);\delta)\cap\Delta^2$ of $(1,0,0)$. If $(x,y,z)$ lies within, $y+z=1-x<\delta$ so it is the image of $\theta(1-t,t,s)$ for some $0\le t<\delta$, $\eta(x,y,z)=F(1-t,t,s)\in U$ as required.
As for the more conceptual proof (for me) we can use chains. Simply partition $\Delta^1\times I$ - which is a square - into two triangles as:

This gives you a $2$-chain (interpret the image as two maps $\Delta^2\to I^2$ the square composed with $F:I^2\to X$) whose boundary is clearly $\sigma_1-\sigma_2$, no constants, as required.
