Path-Homotopic Paths are Homologous(?)
I'm currently re-reading through Hatcher's Algebraic Topology textbook, and the following question came up: Are path-homotopic paths homologous? Hatcher doesn't seem to address this question (that is, not up until page 118), but online sources have expressed affirmation that indeed this statement will hold true. For the purpose of ensuring the correct conclusion has been reached, however, I've decided to reach out on here. I've got a proof written out (see below), though it is possible I've overlooked (a) potential error(s):
Proof. Denote continuous path-homotopic maps $f_0,f_1:[0,1]\to X$ with path-homotopy $f:[0,1]\times[0,1].$ Let us construct the singular $2$-simplex $g:\Delta_2\to X$ (where $\Delta_2=([0,1]\times[0,1])/_{(0,y)\text{~}(0,0)\ \forall y\in[0,1]}$) so that $g(r,\theta)=f(r\tan(\theta),\frac{\theta}{\pi/4})$. Then $\partial_2^X g=f_1-f_0+\hat{x}$ (where $\hat{x}:[0,1]\to X$ denotes some constant map) implies $f_1-f_0\in\text{im}(\partial_2^X),$ and thereby $[f_0]=[f_1]\in H_1(X).$
I appreciate any and all help I can get. Thank you!

Similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4946246/the-first-singular-homology-group-h-1x-and-the-fundamental-group/

Or rather, the exact question is different (you want a proof, they wanted a proof explanation) but the content is very similar and hopefully my answer helps. Hatcher will eventually talk about this; in the appendix to chapter $3$ it is shown/sketched that there is a natural map $\pi_1(X)\to H_1(X)$ and that it is, for path-connected space, the Abelianisation quotient map. In chapter four, further relations between homotopy and homology are discussed

@FShrike Thank you for sharing your response. I believe that should be sufficient, though all I was in need of was confirmation as to whether (i) my proof was fine (which it appears we utilized either very similar or near-identical tactics), and/or (ii) whether the statement is true. Just looking to ensure my intuition is strong.

One thing you might want to keep in mind for the future is our guidelines on questions which primarily ask to verify a proposed proof: "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.
